# CFA in R: The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov) does not appear to be positive definite. What is the problem?

Tags: r-lavaan, factor-analysis

I am trying to calculate a CFA for the Theory of Planned Behaviour (TPB). I have split the 4 factors (Attitude, SubNorm, PBC, Intention) into inverted and non-inverted items. Enclosed is the measurement model.

N = 75. The items were rated on a scale of 1-7.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQCLt.png)

However, after I run the second part (categorical part), I receive a warning message that says:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyedx.png)

Do any of you know the problem and what can be done?

Comment: That message means there is multicollinearity among the parameter estimates, which can happen when you try to estimate too many parameters relative to the sample size.  I already wouldn't recommend fitting such a large model to continuous indicators.  Treating them as categorical would only compound the problem (there are 6 thresholds per item).